# Finding the great circle distance between three points using the Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Unfortunately I was not able to find any code / example how to draw **great circle distance** **between three(3) points on google maps**??

Here is the javascript for two points. How can I make it work with three points?

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var addresses;
var results;
var dist;

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    address1 = document.getElementById("distancefrom").value;
    address2 = document.getElementById("distanceto").value;
    (distance(address1, address2));
}

function distance(add1, add2) {
    if (!geocoder)
        return 'Error, no geocoder';

    addresses = new Array(2);
    addresses[0] = add1;
    addresses[1] = add2;
    results = new Array(2);
    results[0] = new Array(2);
    results[1] = new Array(2);

    results[0][0] = 0; results[0][1] = 0; results[1][0] = 0; results[1][1] = 0.87;
    geocoded(1);
}

function geocoded(i) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresses[i] }, function(res, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            results[i][0] = parseFloat(res[0].geometry.location.lat());
            results[i][1] = parseFloat(res[0].geometry.location.lng());
            i--;

            if (i >= 0)
                geocoded(i);
            else {
                var latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0][0], results[0][1]);
                var latlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(results[1][0], results[1][1]);

                dist = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latlng1, latlng2)/1000;
                var dmi = 0.539957*dist;
                document.getElementById('totaldistancemiles').value = dmi.toFixed(2);
                document.getElementById('totaldistancekm').value = dist.toFixed(2);
                showMap(latlng1,latlng2);
            }
        }
    });
}

function showMap(location1,location2) {
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng((location1.lat()+location2.lat())/2,
    (location1.lng()+location2.lng())/2);
    faddress1 = document.getElementById("distancefrom").value;
    faddress2 = document.getElementById("distanceto").value;
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 1,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        location1,
        location2
    ];
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: .5,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeWeight: 3
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: flightPlanCoordinates,
        strokeColor: "#000000",
        strokeOpacity: .5,
        strokeWeight: 0
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    var igreen= 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85343999/igreen.gif';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        icon: igreen, 
        position: location1
    });
    var latlngbounds;
    latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    latlngbounds.extend( location1);
    latlngbounds.extend( location2);
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent(faddress1);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map, 
        icon: igreen, 
        position: location2
    });

    var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow2.setContent(faddress2);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function() {
        infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
    });
}
```

Comment: you didn't provide javascript, anyway as far as I understand the great circle distance, if you want to compute it between three points it should be the concatenation of distances between pairs of points, so where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses  Googles [**geometry**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) library to calculate distances between points.The locations are stored in this case in an array, but can be obtained from textboxes etc. The distances are given in metres .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var coords = [
      [35.733972, -5.881999],
      [35.734077, -5.881033],
      [35.736898, -5.877771],
];
function calcDistance() { 
  var first = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0][0],coords[0][1]);
  var second = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[1][0],coords[1][1]);
  var third = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[2][0],coords[2][1]);
  var distance1 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(first, second);
  var distance2 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(first, third);
  var distance3 = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(second, third);
  showDistance(distance1,distance2,distance3);
}   
 function showDistance(distance1,distance2,distance3) {        
   document.write("Distance1 "+distance1 + " metres <br>"); 
   document.write("Distance2 "+distance2 + " metres <br>"); 
   document.write("Distance3 "+distance3 + " metres <br>"); 

}
```

Comment: Dear DavidNow I understand better but I could not provide my code since could not sent in javascript format,....can you tell me what to do with my code (short one) how I could send it over for your kind review

Comment: Hello David I have managed to send code under same question a bit modified,.....do you want and HTML ?

Comment: David,...sorry to bother you,..if you decide to help me out you can forget parts of the code to calculate and present distances along great circle,...I need only to show, in the google map,...sectors (GCD) between 3 points,...in all combinations: points A,B,C ,...NEED gcd SECTORS ON THE googgle MAP with markers: A-B-C, A-C, B-C !!Thanks in advance and no hard fillings if you have no any spare time to help me out !